# Where can I find the pkcs11 library for armhf?

Tags: arm, pcscd

I am looking for the `pkcs11` library for using Gemalto IDPrime .NET smartcards on Ubuntu 13.04 armhf.

The listed libraries for Ubuntu:

http://ppa.launchpad.net/gemaltocrypto/dotnet+2.2.0.12/ubuntu/dists/raring/main/binary-armhf/Packages

does not show the armhf libraries. Can anyone point me to the right page to download the library for armhf?

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the [PPA's package list](http://ppa.launchpad.net/gemaltocrypto/dotnet+2.2.0.12/ubuntu/pool/main/libg/libgtop11dotnet/), there's only i386 and amd64 packages available.

You can contact the [PPA maintainer](https://launchpad.net/~barnabasdk) to request building armhf packages.